# Stop all Clearcase services on AIX system - Stop completly Clearcase

Tags: clearcase

How to stop completly Clearcase:
 - ALBD (Atria Location Broker), albd_server.
 - IBM Rational Lock Manager, lockmgr.
 - Rational Credential Manager.
 - MVFS Service, I think is not possible because is a kernel module.

Chapter init_ccase of Reference manual only provides one command line:

```
/etc/rc.atria { start | stop }
```

For information:
 - AIX d1dw753 1 7 00F60BAD4C00 (uname -a)
 - ClearCase version 8.0.1.1 (cleartool –VerAll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to be root.

[Stop all Clearcase services on AIX system - Stop completly Clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472078/stop-all-clearcase-services-on-aix-system-stop-completly-clearcase)

Second, the [official documentation `init_ccase`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/init_ccase.htm) does mention, in addition of `/etc/rc.atria { start | stop }`:

> - Unexports any view/VOB combinations that were exported through /etc/exports.mvfs to enable non-ClearCase access
> - Unmounts all VOBs
> - Kills the vob_server processes for VOBs whose storage directories are on the local host
> - Kills the albd_server process, which also causes view_server, db_server, and vobrpc_server processes to exit
> - Kills the lockmgr process
> - (On AIX 4) **Unloads the MVFS from the operating system kernel**
> - Unmounts the viewroot directory

So regarding MVFS and AIX 4, the "[Loading and Unloading Kernel Extensions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.kernextc/kernextc02.htm)" page suggests [`kmod_unload` command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.ktechrf1/kmod_unload.htm).

That would stop *completely* ClearCase.

The commands listed in "[Uninstall ClearCase 7.1 on Linux or Unix](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21376016)" (section AIX), like `rmvfs mvfs`, would be "too much" here.